# Check whether value becomes 1 and remains 1

Tags: python

Examples:

```
(0, 0, 1, 1)    => True (becomes 1 and remains 1)
(0, 0, 0)       => False (never becomes 1)
(0, 1, 1, 0, 1) => False (becomes 1 but goes back to 0)
(1, 1, 1)       => True (ok to become 1 right away)
```

I have a finite generator that gives me signal values, `0` for "not done" and `1` for "done". It's supposed to reach "done" and then remain "done". I want to check that.

Here's an example generator (with hardcoded values) and how I want to use it:

```
def signal():
    yield from (0, 0, 1, 1)

>>> check(signal())
True
```

I have a solution, but it seems long and complicated. There must be a better way! Any and all ideas are welcome.

```
def check(s):
    done = False
    for x in s:
        if x:
            done = True
            break
    if not done:
        return False
    for x in s:
        if not x:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `def is_sorted(l): return all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in range(len(l)-1))`

Comment: @erip Doesn't work on a generator.

Comment: @erip Plus if it were a list, you'd get my second example wrong (`[0, 0, 0]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to check

- if you ever hit a 1, and
- if you ever hit a zero *after* you have hit a 1.

```
def check(s):
    on = False
    for v in s:
        if on and not v:
            return False
        on = v
    return bool(on)
```

Or, put more arithmetically, you want your sequence to be monotonic increasing, and for the last value to be 1 rather than 0.

```
def check(s):
    last = 0
    for v in s:
        if v < last:
            return False
        last = v
    return bool(last)
```

Or if you're looking for a *clever* solution rather than a clear one, as long as you're sure your sequence must be a generator, you can exploit short-circuiting and do this:

```
def check(s):
    return any(s) and all(s)
```

`any` returns true as soon as it finds a 1 (and stops consuming the generator), and `all` returns true if all the subsequent elements are 1.

Comment: Last one was the goal, as hinted at by the question's last sentence. (As commented elsewhere, this was intended to be a fun little puzzle, hope nobody minds :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use an iterator with the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```py
def check(s):
    i = iter(s)
    for v in i:
        if v:
            return all(i)
    return False
```

First of all we create an iterator on the input iterable.

Then, if all values were `0`, the loop will exhaust and return `False`.

Once `1` is met, this will return whether all subsequent elements are `1` as well. Because we convert to an iterator, the `all` function will only look at the elements **after** the first `1`.

---

- If you know your input will always be an iterator, you can get rid of the first line (`i = iter(s)`) and replace `i` with `s`.

Comment: Time to admit that it's intended to be a fun little puzzle around a beautiful solution. You're close. (There's a hint in the question, but I don't think you need it.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def check(s):
    rest = dropwhile(lambda x: not x, s)
    try:
        first = next(rest)
        return True if all(x for x in (first, *rest)) else False
    except StopIteration:
        return False
```

With

```
assert check((0, 0, 1, 1)) == True
assert check((0, 0, 0)) == False
assert check((0, 1, 1, 0, 1)) == False
assert check((1, 1, 1)) == True
```

We need to use a `try/except` block because

```
if all(x for x in [])
```

returns `True` as well, thus we need to make sure the generator is not yet empty with `next(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
def check(generator):
    return 1 in generator and 0 not in generator
```

This works thanks to short-circuit evaluation, because `1 in generator` consumes all elements from the generator until a `1` is reached, and `0 not in generator` asserts that there are no following zeros in the remaining elements.

EDIT - just saw khelwood's answer, which is equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice alternative, and a variant is the shortest I found: `return(1in s)>(0in s)` (if one were to code golf)

Answer (score -1):

```
def check(s):
    int_v = int("".join([str(i) for i in s]), 2)
    b_v = bin(int_v)[2:]
    if all(b_v):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I tested your check function, but I got this result. 

(0, 0, 1, 1) => False
(0, 0, 0) => False
(0, 1, 1, 0, 1) => False
(1, 1, 1) => True

Comment: This always returns `True`.